# Duda sobre Api Rest en Laravel/Passport

Tags: laravel, passport, guzzle

en mi proyecto estoy implementando la llamada con un Api Rest con Laravel/Passport, usando Guzzle como cliente. Mi intención es que el Guzzle envie un post para comprobar un usuario en otra plataforma que tengo para asi centralizarlo todo en una misma base de datos. Son varias plataformas consultando la base de datos de una sola. Se recibe esa petición y se realiza la consulta en la base de datos, si se devuelve al cliente guzzle la respuesta en JSON.

La duda que me viene, llega a consecuencia de errores que me aparecen a realizar la petición por problemas en la codificación de UTF-8, precisamente cuando se realiza por Eloquend la consulta... si no realizo la consulta, me devuelve un JSON perfectamente de prueba, asi que la petición llega correctamente a su destino.

¿Es posible realizar así una consulta SQL por este método Api Rest? En una ocasión incluso, con otra de las plataformas logré realizar la consulta pero se intentaba conectar a la base de datos local, cuando deberia de hacerlo en la remota.

Perdón por no poner nada de código, no lo tengo en mi equipo, este problema me surgió en el trabajo.

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano.

---

**EDITADO:**

Gracias por la respuesta, he reproducido en mi equipo dos proyectos laravel para hacer lo que quiero conseguir.

Tengo dos proyectos, uno que llamaremos "General" con Passport configurado y el cual recibirá la peticion y consultará en la base de datos si el usuario es el correcto o no, devolvera por JSON la respuesta. Indico que solo el proyecto "General" cuenta con base de datos.

Aqui el controlador que recibe la petición:

```
class UsuariosController extends Controller {

public function index(){
    echo "hola";
}

public function externalUserLogin(Request $request){
    $result = Usuarios::login($request->usuario, $request->password);

    if($result["response"] == "fail"){
        return response()->json([
            'message' => $result["message"]
        ], 401);
    }

    if(is_null($usuario = Usuarios::getById($result["id_usuario"]))){
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Error cargando usuario'
        ], 401);
    }

    $tokenResult = $usuario->createToken('Personal Access Token');

    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    /*if ($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);*/
    $token->save();

    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'usuario' => $usuario
    ], 200);
}
```

Aqui os muestro el modelo Usuario, se que Laravel tiene un modelo nativo pero preferí crear uno propio:

```
class Usuarios extends Model {
use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

const ID = 'usu_Nid';

protected $table = 'usuarios';
protected $primaryKey = self::ID;
public $timestamps = false;
protected $fillable = [self::ID, 'usu_Clogin', 'usu_Cpass', 'usu_Cnombre'];

public function getId() { return $this->attributes[self::ID]; }
public function setId($value) { $this->attributes[self::ID] = $value; }

public function getLogin() { return $this->attributes['usu_Clogin']; }
public function setLogin($value) { $this->attributes['usu_Clogin'] = $value; }

public function getPass() { return $this->attributes['usu_Cpass']; }
public function setPass($value) { $this->attributes['usu_Cpass'] = $value; }

public function getNombre() { return $this->attributes['usu_Cnombre']; }
public function setNombre($value) { $this->attributes['usu_Cnombre'] = $value; }

public function toArray(){
    return array(
        'id' => $this->getId(),
        'login' => $this->getLogin(),
        'pass' => $this->getPass(),
        'nombre' => $this->getNombre()
    );
}

public static function getById($id) { return self::where(self::ID, "=", $id)->first(); }
public static function getByLogin($login) { return self::where('usu_Clogin', "=", $login)->first(); }

public static function login($usuario, $password){
    if(is_null($usuario = self::getByLogin($usuario))) return array("response" => "fail", "message" => "Usuario no existe");
    if($usuario->getPass() != $password) return array("response" => "fail", "message" => "Password incorrecta");
    return array("response" => "success", "id_usuario" => $usuario->getId());
}
```

Luego tengo un proyecto al que llamaremos "Cliente", el cual con GuzzleHttp realiza la petición post, es donde el usuario realiza el login mediante un Form.

Aqui el controlador donde recibe ese Form y realiza la petición:

```
class LoginController extends Controller {
public function userLogin(Request $request){
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
    $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'];

    $res = $client->post('http://localhost/plataformaGeneral/public/api/auth/login', [
        /*'headers'=>$headers,*/
        'form_params' => [
            'usuario' => $request->usuario,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ]
    ]);
    return $res = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
}
```

Comentarles que haciendo pruebas con esto, ya no tengo errores de codificación. El problema que encuentro es en la respuesta "QLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database". Parece que el proyecto "Cliente" intenta conectarse el mismo a una base de datos propia, ya que si en el .ENV le pongo el nombre de la base de datos del proyecto "General", si funciona. Pero entiendo que no deberia importarle al proyecto Cliente nada de la base de datos, ya que es el proyecto General quien recibe los parametros de usuario y contraseña, y consulta a su base de datos, devolviendo el resultado.

Muchas gracias, espero haberlo explicado bien. Seguramente me abre comido alguna llave copiando aqui el codigo, pero es solo para que vean el funcionamiento.

Comment: Hola @danjim21 esta muy buena y curiosa tu pregunta, aunque has expresado el inconveniente con tu código es bueno colocarlo para poder replicarlo y darte una respuesta certera del caso. Además incluir que investigaciones independientes has realizado, es algo así como: Qué tienes, qué esperas, y qué hace actualmente. y así la respuesta no es eliminada o mal valorada. Modifica la respuesta y te esperamos. Saludos!

Comment: Os comento, ya lo solucione, había que cambiar del .env el nombre de la variable DB_DATABASE, por ejemplo XX_DB_DATABASE=NOMBREDB. Por lo visto el proyecto cliente confunde la base de datos remota porque coincide ese nombre de variable.

Comment: Perfecto! Añade la respuesta por si otro usuario consulta la pregunta la encuentre como respondida y válida!